# Sub post not showing in wordpress admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to show all the post (including sub post) in wp-admin. but the post which are having parent are not showing in the list of post although the count is giving like 142 post but showing 42 out of 142 since 100 posts are sub posts.
I installed a plugin wp sub post for this where it gave me an option to add a post as parent but not coming in wp-admin.
what can i do for this?

In database it is stored with post_parent id where as the normal have post_parent= 0

Answer (score 0):

try the following code. make sure value of post_parent=-1 to get all posts

```
<?php $args = array(
'posts_per_page'   => 5,
'offset'           => 0,
'category'         => '',
'orderby'          => 'post_date',
'order'            => 'DESC',
'include'          => '',
'exclude'          => '',
'meta_key'         => '',
'meta_value'       => '',
'post_type'        => 'post',
'post_mime_type'   => '',
'post_parent'      => '-1',
'post_status'      => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true ); ?>
<?php $post_arr=get_posts($args);?>
<?php echo '<pre>';print_r($post_arr);echo '</pre>'?>
```

Comment: Where shall i put this in wp-admin ??

Comment: can you send your plugin name or url

Comment: Plugin name is "wp sub post". where its taking and showing the post properly but in wp-admin in the list of all post not coming.

Comment: you need to write the url of plugin as it is not searchable by name 'wpsub post'